# Clone HTML Element vs creating it with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting a list of employees via an ajax request.  I'm then creating a bunch of divs with their name address telephone etc.  These new elements also have some buttons that provide functionality.  I have been using this approach:

```
var Employee = function(params) {
  this.name = params.name;
  this.hrid = params.hrid;

  this.initialize = function() {
    this.container = document.createElement('div');
    this.contName = document.createElement('div');
    this.contHRID = document.createElement('div');
    this.myButton = document.createElement('button');

    this.contName.innerHTML = this.name;
    this.contHRID.innerHTML = this.hrid;
    this.container.appendChild(this.contName);
    this.container.appendChild(this.contHRID);
    this.container.appendChild(this.myButton);

    this.addObservers();
  }

  this.addObservers = function() {
    this.myButton.observer = this.dostuff.bind(this);
    this.myButton.addEventListener('click', this.myButton.observer);
  }

  this.dostuff = function() {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

This approach works well for me, but I'm wondering if I would be better off creating a hidden div somewhere with the HTML already built and cloning that.

I would very much like to hear some thoughts on which approach is better, or if it's a six-of-one type of situation.

Comment: `cloneNode()` is faster than `createElement()`. To start with, I would create one div and clone the next ones instead of creating them in a row. In case of hidden HTML div vs `createElement()` it depends on the situation. If you need to clone it once, then it would be similar either way. If it has to be cloned a few times, then it might work out better with the hidden div. I used a similar approach myself. I created a hidden div (complete with child nodes) and I used the JS to fill the innerHTML/textContent according to the situation but in that case only ONE div was visible at a time.

Comment: this site says the opposite, that createElement is faster across browsers https://jsperf.com/clonenode-vs-createelement-performance/2